# Parse PHP source codes and extract some informations

Tags: php, parsing

I have some files with this structure:

```
<?php
    echo "something";

    switch($_GET['action'])
    {
         case 'step1':
           echo 'somethings';
         break;

         case 'step2':
           echo 'somethings';
           switch($_GET['section'])
           {
               case 'section1':
                  echo 'somethings';
               break;
           }
         break;

         case 'step3':
           echo 'somethings';
         break;

    }
?>
```

In my BackOffice, I want to parse these files and show for each one the "cases" of "switch($_GET['action'])". In this exemple it will be "Step1", "step2" and "step3".

N.B: I do not to parser the switch($_GET['section']). I Just wan to extract the cases of switch($_GET['action']).

I tried the "token_get_all" but I didn't end with the result i'm looking for.

Thank you for your help, i'll appreciate.

Comment: So what is the expected result for the provided code?

Comment: Do you have to use PHP to parse the PHP?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? I advice you to use `var_dump($_GET);` in the first place to see what you have as parameters in there, then you can advance.

Comment: `token_get_all` _is_ what you'd need in PHP, that or write your own PHP parser in PHP, which way masochistic madness lies...

Comment: Thanks all for your advices. The expected result for the above exemple is array('step1,'step2','step3').

Comment: Why don't you just create that array initially `$caseValues = array('step1', 'step2', 'step3');`, then do `case $caseValues[0]:`, etc.?

Comment: The expected result for the provided code is irrelevant. As are the contents of `$_GET`. It seems that the OP wants to parse the code and build an array of the case values used for the `$_GET['action']` switch.

Comment: @showdev so you think what I'm trying to do isn't possible ?

Comment: No, I don't think that at all. I was responding to other comments that seemed off-topic or not constructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you probably need a full PHP parser, that builds up what amounts to an AST.

You can then walk over the AST, find the switch statements, check for the ones that reference a subtree containing $_GET['ACTION'] by writing picky procedural code to inspect nodes, climb up and down the tree, etc., pick out the cases and finally print them, achieving your goal.

token_get_all is one place to start, if you want to write your own PHP parser.  That takes probably far more effort than you think; the language is complicated and not documented very well.

There is a PHP parser in PHP, coded using token_get_all; see http://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser.  I don't know how robust it is; I've interacted here at SO with the guy who wrote it, who seems clever enough.  It claims that it does not parse expressions in detail, but you don't appear to need more than that.  You'll get to code the search for switch and cases by clambering up and down whatever syntax tree he has defined.
[Actually, you may the expression content, if you want to discriminate on the content
of the switch expression].

If you want a more sophisticated PHP parser, one tested by fire, does expressions in excruciating details, that is designed to do these kinds of tasks you can ask for more details and I'll tell you about our commercial version.  [I'd put a link here so you could find it without this dance, but some SO moderators don't like that, so you have to ask]. Ours also lets you define patterns in terms of surface syntax, e.g.,

```
       pattern targeted_switches(cases:case_clauses)=
            "   switch($_GET['ACTION']){ \cases } ";
```

You can ask our tool to find ASTs that match this pattern for you, and bind subtrees to the pattern variables listed in the head clause ("cases") and used in the pattern body ("\cases") as placeholders.  With \cases bound, you can match to another pattern:

```
      pattern  cases(case_target:expression, s: statement,rest_of_cases:case_clauses)=
            "   case \case_target: \s \rest_of_cases ";
```

which would find the first case in list of "\cases", bind \case_target to the value you want to print, and bind \rest_of_cases to the rest of case list.  You can use out tools to print that bound \case_target, producing your result, and then repeat this step on the rest of the list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give me a link for your product ?

Comment: See our DMS toolkit code manipulaton engine http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html and DMS's PHP5 front end http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/PHPFrontEnd.html

Comment: Please check your email. Thank you.

Comment: At least  when you suggest your solutions, try to answer to your emails and not to ignore it.  Thanks anyway. Solution abandanned.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience; I just checked my email inbox for unanswered emails, and don't see one.  Can I have a domain name so that I may check to see whether we received email from you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Domain name (high-dev.com). Email sent to "idbaxter@...."

Comment: Will ask the sys admin folks on Monday to look into this.

Comment: Found it.  Further discussion through the email contact.